# what's the part of speech of "underground" in following sentence

Tags: grammar, adjectives, spoken-english

In the following sentence from CNN:

> Such fires were once plentiful in Azerbaijan, but because they led to a reduction of **gas pressure *underground***, interfering with commercial gas extraction, most have been snuffed out.

The word **"underground"**, I think it's an adjective, which modifies **"gas pressure"**. so it's similar to "...they led to a reduction of the gas pressure which is underground".

If then, the sentence must be "...they led to a reduction of underground gas pressure" (underground precedes gas pressure)

Please help me to clarify the structure. I appreciate all your help :)

Comment: Mobile sucks. Search for "whiz deletion".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this is Mama talking ; this is Mama's talking](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32948/this-is-mama-talking-this-is-mamas-talking)